# PHP base 64 to image conversion

Tags: php

I have been trying this code to convert an image to base64 and then again saving it to an image file to disk but at the end i get an image file with invalid image text.

```
<?php

$b64image = base64_encode(file_get_contents('1.png'));

file_put_contents('abc.png',$b64image);

?>
```

Comment: You *do not want* to base64 encode an image. You only need to encode the image if you plan on sending in an email or printing into a style/html src block.

Comment: Actually what i want is to first convert an image to base 64 then save it to disk again.

Comment: Why do you want to base 64 encode a png file?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: base64 is a *text* format, not a binary/image format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image <s>cannot be be encoded with base64</s> can be encoded with base64, but not many image viewers will actually show an image encoded with base64. You need to `base64_decode` the image before storing it in another file, so image viewers can read your image correctly.

Comment: More precisely, it *can* be encoded, but the result is not valid image data in its own right.  No image viewers I know of recognize and decode base64 data.

Comment: ok my problem is when i try to convert any bnary format to image file it gives invalid image.

Comment: @h_a86: How are you doing that "conversion"?

Comment: @h_a86: Are you trying to create a handy image representation of the data inside some arbitrary binary file?  To make graphics similar to the discussion on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_block_chaining#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29 ?

Comment: @h_a86: Why are you encoding in base64 in the first place?

Comment: Actually it was a testing. just converting image to base 64 and then back base64 to image. Thanks for your reply.